# Can we create a chaotic integer-valued system?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, intuition, integers, chaos-theory

Can we create a system of recurrences that exhibits chaotic behavior, with the restriction that we are only allowed to use the integers?

For example, we could create a system:

$$
\begin{align}
a(t) &= a(t-1)^2 +b(t-2) + 3c(t-1)  \\
b(t) &= 3 + a(t-1)  \\
c(t) &= b(t-1)b(t-2)^2 \\
& \vdots
\end{align}
$$

I'm of course looking for a system that stays within some boundaries for certain intial conditions.  In other words, maybe:

$$
\begin{align}
-20 \le a(t) \le 100  \\
15 \le b(t) \le 50  \\
-100 \le c(t) \le 100 \\
& \vdots
\end{align}
$$

Of course, all of the functions I mentioned are just examples.  The main problem is that the functions must exhibit what I will call "totally integer functions".  That is to say that they must be functions from integers to integers.  That disallows division, since we could get a non-integer result.  It also disallows floors, ceilings, and modulo functions, for example.  I also cannot use function composition, unless the total depth of recursion is less than $\log{(\log{(n)})}$ for a function with all values between $-n$ and $n$.

Comment: First, you have to define "chaotic". The usual definitions include "sensitive dependence on initial conditions", the idea that if you change $a_0$ by even a tiny bit, the change in $a_n$ will be enormous before too long. But if you are restricting to integers, there is no such thing as changing $a_0$ by a tiny bit, so there's is no way to define sensitive dependence, much less to produce it. If you have another definition in mind, you must state it explicitly, precisely, and clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Digital computers are integer systems.   Can we create chaos in an digital computer?   Does a system of NAND gates pass your requirements?

Also look at cellular automata in Wolfram's New Kind of Science.

Answer (score 0):

The system you describe because of its bounded integer nature, have bounded states (less than 1 millions in your example), thus chaotic behavior will be extremely poor. Best you can do is look for Pseudorandom number generator.

Comment: A pseudorandom number generator isn't chaotic either, though perhaps it is a good example that such a system can never be chaotic

Comment: @Yves Lhuillier Are you sure?